# Is this parallel? "He's not only the Hair Club president but also a client.'

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, syntactic-analysis

Are the following sentences grammatically parallel?

1. "He's not only the Hair Club president but also a client." (No comma.)
2. "Not only is he the Hair Club president, but also he is a client." (Comma.)
3. "He not only is the Hair Club president but also is a client." (No comma.)

Answer (score 1):

What Sy Sperling not only said in his television commercials, but also legally trademarked (!), was this:

"I'm not only the Hair Club president, I'm also a client!"(TM)

http://tinyurl.com/Hair-Club-Trademarks

And yes, Mr. Sperling's usage was grammatically parallel. :-)